# how to obtain a complete clockwise rotation in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, rotation, transition

I want a square to complete a full clockwise rotation on itself, after a pause on the half of the rotation.
The following code makes it doing an half rotation clockwise, and the other half counter-clockwise, contrary to what I expect.

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var s = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("x", -25)
  .attr("y", -25)
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");

s
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("transform", "translate(100,100) rotate(180)")
  .transition()
  .delay(1000)
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("transform", "translate(100,100) rotate(360)");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ffd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

I can hack such a code splitting the second half rotation in two quarter clockwise rotations, but I wish to know if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use D3v3 it does not rotate to 180 degrees, if I switch to D3v4 it rotates to 180.

You can interpolate to 359.99. It does not follow the string interpolator from the docs, because you also get `scale()` in the transform.

```
translate(100, 100) rotate(359.989990234375) scale(0.999,0.999)
```

This does not happen if you write your own interpolator.

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var s=svg.append("rect")
.attr("width",50)
.attr("height",50)
.attr("x",-25)
.attr("y",-25)
.attr("fill","red")
.attr("transform","translate(100,100) rotate(0)");

s
.transition()
.duration(3000)
.ease(d3.easeLinear)
.attr("transform","translate(100,100) rotate(180)")
.transition()
.delay(2000)
.duration(3000)
.ease(d3.easeLinear)
.attrTween("transform", () => d3.interpolate("translate(100,100) rotate(180)", "translate(100,100) rotate(360)") );
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

The culprit here is D3 itself, not any SVG spec.

The problem is that your transition uses `d3.interpolateTransform`, as we can see [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/2a44471cc975328a4b6dc5787a8ebe2dfa8afadc/src/transition/attr.js#L69):

```
var fullname = namespace(name), i = fullname === "transform" ? interpolateTransform : interpolate;
```

This is v4 source code, not v3, but the principle is the same, as you can see in the actual v3 code:

```
var interpolate = nameNS == "transform" ? d3_interpolateTransform : d3_interpolate, name = d3.ns.qualify(nameNS);
```

Then, if we look in the source code for `interpolateTransform` (again, v4, but v3 is almost the same), we'll see that it uses a function called [`parseSvg`](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate/blob/888f9fc44bd6d1e70f1b0f4c0063ae628bb14b71/src/transform/parse.js#L18) that calculates the matrix for the new transform:

```
function parseSvg(value) {
  if (value == null) return identity;
  if (!svgNode) svgNode = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
  svgNode.setAttribute("transform", value);
  if (!(value = svgNode.transform.baseVal.consolidate())) return identity;
  value = value.matrix;
  return decompose(value.a, value.b, value.c, value.d, value.e, value.f);
}
```

That function is generating `0` as the final value in the matrix when you pass `rotate(360)` to it (the actual value is `-2.4492935982947064e-16`, which is practically zero).

**Solution**

There are several possible solutions here, the easiest one is using `interpolateString` instead of `interpolateTransform`.

Also, since your code uses D3 v3, you can take advantage of `d3.transform()`, which was removed in v4/v5:

```
d3.interpolateString(d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")), "translate(100,100) rotate(360)")
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var s = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("x", -25)
  .attr("y", -25)
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)");

s.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("transform", "translate(100,100) rotate(180)")
  .transition()
  .delay(1000)
  .duration(1000)
  .attrTween("transform", function() {
    return d3.interpolateString(d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")), "translate(100,100) rotate(360)")
  });
```

```html
<svg></svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```